# Screen halts while booting into new linux kernel

Tags: boot, grub2, kernel

I started learning about the Linux kernel, and I tried to add new system calls. For that, I downloaded the latest `Linux kernel source (linux-5.11.2)` on `Ubuntu 20.04` and compiled and built the kernel by using a sequence of commands:

> cd linux-5.11.2/
> sudo make menuconfig
> sudo make 
> sudo make modules_install install

After compiling and building the kernel, some new files are generated in the `/boot/` directory

> initrd.img-5.11.2
> System.map-5.11.2
> vmlinuz-5.11.2
> config-5.11.2

Now, the problem is when I try to boot into the linux-5.11.2 kernel after the restart, the screen looks like this:

> Loading Linux 5.11.2 ...
> Loading initial ramdisk ...

And, the screen halts on this. I am not able to figure out what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Disable Secure Boot.

Comment: @Pilot6 I have disabled the secure boot but still getting problem

Comment: Generally this is a wrong way of installing kernel to Ubuntu. You should build a deb package and install it properly. Also if you have a proprietary GPU driver, it won't work with this kernel.

Comment: @Pilot6 okay, thanks